# RxJS.fromWebSocket with Socket.io

Tags: node.js, sockets, websocket, rxjs

I'm trying to create a Subject using Rx.DOM.fromWebSocket with Socket.io. I'm really lost - where do I find the protocol for the Socket.io implementation?

```
var rxSocket = Rx.DOM.fromWebSocket(
        'ws://localhost:12345',
        'ws',
        function (e) {
            console.log('Opening');
        });

rxSocket.subscribe(function (next) {
    console.log('Received data: ' + next);
});

rxSocket.onNext('data');
```

This is what I've got right now. I'm trying to connect locally, to my server running Socket.io. When I just used the standard `io.connect()` everything runs smoothly, so my server is up and running Socket.io. I've tried to Google but don't know where to find the socket protocol implementation for Socket.io.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Socket.io doesn't serve websockets, it serves 'websockets', websockets if available but fallbacks if not, even if it makes a websocket connection it doesn't send the kind of messages rxSocket is going to expect.  If you want to use Rx.DOM.fromWebSocket you should instead simple use the ws module.

So options:

- RX.DOM.formWebSocket + ws  (only support real websockets, but make things nice)
- socket.io + hacks (full browser/ 'helpful' proxy support, but clunky)

Comment: Yeah, I figured it had something to do with the fallbacks, but thought it would be able to use the ws-connection if declared explicitly. Thanks for your answer. Upvoting and replying with my own answer when I've implemented a raw WS.

Edit: Do you have an example of how the "clunky" implementation of Socket.io would look like?

Comment: Basically just use io.connect() then publish the events to RX

Comment: @Apansson just take the [source of fromWebSocket](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS-DOM/blob/master/src/websocket.js) and replace the websocket API with `socket.io` API (i.e. replace the `.addEventListener(...)` stuff with `.on(...)`, replace event names, etc), use `Observable.create` instead of `AnonymousObservable`, use `Observer.create` instead of `Observercreate`.  It is fairly straight-forward to follow the formula and make it work with `socket.io`.

Answer (score 7):

Another approach is to use RxJS Observable.fromEvent.

```
var socket = io('ws://localhost:8080');

var dataStream = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(socket, 'data');

dataStream.subscribe(function(payload) {
  console.log(payload);
});
```

In this example, allow socket.io to handle the connection.

RxJs handles the events and creates an Observable stream to subscribe to.

Answer (score 0):

Shamless self promotion, I know, but I made [rxjs-socket.io](https://gitlab.com/moshmage/rxjs-socket.io/wikis/home) for this propose exactlty. with it, all you really have to do is:

```
import {IO, ioEvent} from 'rxjs-socket.io'

const socket = new IO();
const onHelloWorld = new ioEvent({name: "hello-world", once: false, count: 0});

socket.listenToEvent(onHelloWorld);
socket.connect('http://localhost:1337');

onHelloWorld.event$.subscribe((state) => {
    console.log('new state', state);
});
```